# Why do i get Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword?

Tags: c#, winforms, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass an string by reference from From1 to Form2, want to modify the string in Form2 and use the altered value in Form1.
This is my code:

Inside Form1.cs:

```
 private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
          
            string text = "aaa";
            Form frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.ShowDialog(ref text); 
        }
```

Inside Form2.cs

```
public void ShowDialog(ref string von1)
        {
           
            textBox1.Text = von1;
            this.ShowDialog(); 
            von1 = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

I'm not able to compile this project because im getting the error:

Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword CS1615

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Change `Form frm2 = new Form2();` to `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();`

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper that was the solution.... thanks